# Access a method of a class contained as a vector of pointers to that class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a vector of pointers to objects defined as:

```
 std::vector<queuedImage*> imgBuffer;
```

I pass it to the constructor of a class by reference:

```
processThread::processThread(std::vector<queuedImage*> &queueRef);
```

Within the class processThread I define:

```
std::vector<queuedImage*> *q;
```

And within the constructor I make the assignment:

```
q = &queueRef;
```

When I come to access elements of the vector which is already populated with objects, the size of the vector is as expected when accessed as:

```
int qSize = q->size();
```

Which makes me assume that this should be valid:

```
q[0]->getData()
```

Where getData is a member of queuedImage.

However, when I compile this, it is apparently not valid as:

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<queuedImage*>’
```

But when I use the . operator instead:

```
q[0].getData()
```

I get the compilation error:

```
error: ‘class std::vector<queuedImage*>’ has no member named ‘getData’
```

I think that I must be accessing the method incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That constructor and the `q` pointer seems like a dangerous combination. What if the variable you pass to the constructor goes out of scope before the object is destructed? Then your pointer `q` will be left hanging.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue here as the vector is defined before an infinite loop which acts as a state machine - so it will never go out of scope. Is there a better way of passing the vector to get around this? Surely the only fix is to copy the object into the constructor which would be really slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing `q[0]`, you're not accessing the first element of the vector, you're actually dereferencing the pointer. `q[0]` == `*q` == a vector.

What you want to do is call `[0]` on the vector that `q` is pointing to. To do that, you have to dereference `q` first:

```
(*q)[0]->getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
(*q)[0]->getData();
```

But why you are unnecessarily creating pointer to vector when you already accepted vector by reference.

Comment: The pointer is accessed in another method of the class, not the constructor. It is just 'initialised' in the constructor. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Besides fixing the syntactical errors to dereference that unnecessary pointer to the vector

```
 (*q)[0]->getData()
```

you ***seriously*** should consider using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) e.g.

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<queuedImage>>
```

or

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<queuedImage>>
```

to hold references in vectors, rather than raw pointers.

Which smart pointer type actually to use depends on your use case.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this other than garbage collection? I thought vectors handle this?

Comment: @user2290362 No, vectors don't handle any kind of _garbage collection_. If that's your actual approach, your code will certainly leak memory.